# Post to Laravel 5 from 3rd party API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm using Laravel 5 to build a basic app.

I'm using a third party SMS gateway which takes an SMS and `POST` the results to my app. I'm testing it locally using Postman for Chrome, and Requestb.in

**My Problem:**
When I try to POST to my app, I get a "whoops" error from Laravel, status code 405.

**My Hunch:**
I have a feeling this is because of default CSRF failing. The request is coming from outside of my app's ecosystem.

**In my routes I have:**

```
Route::post('/sms/', 'SMSController@create');
```

**SMSController:**

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
       //keeping it simple for now
        return view('hello');
    }
```

**Question:** Is this the problem, and if so, how do I disable CSRF from one route only.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that L5 now has exclusion lists as a feature:

```
<?php namespace APPNAMESPACE\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
          'example1',
          'example2/example3',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change handle method in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` to do so.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    protected $excludes = [ // Route patterns
        'sms',
        'sms/*'
    ];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach ($this->excludes as $pattern) 
        {
            if ($request->is($pattern)) 
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
```

> **Update**
>
> According to [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection), from Laravel 5.1+ you are
>   able to define the URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification
>   by adding them to the `$except` property of the VerifyCsrfToken
>   middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = [
        'sms/*',
    ];
```

Comment: I'd create an array instead of a variable and use in_array instead of comparing the values.

Comment: @zeratulmdq I improved it by defining an array of exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Should be getting a token mismatch error, unfortunately CSRF is baked in - here is a way to extend the middleware and add an exclusion list:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-disable-csrf-middleware-on-certain-routes

Comment: You should post the relevant code with your answer what if tomorrow the link you posted is not available anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

After trying different option like you all, my search ceased when I found the simple and short code to pass all the `api/*` calls in the `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` just replace this code,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    if( ! $request->is('api/*')){
        return parent::handle($request, $next); 
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

It works like charm in Laravel 5. Although, the new laravel 5.1 this could be done with this code,

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];
}
```

This can be found here [Laravel VerifyCsrfToken.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php)